# Create density plots with facet_wrap in R adding lines and datapoints that represent other columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to create density plots of two variables, faceted by country. I know how to do this.

But then there are ther variables that would be better to visualize as lines or means:

- `party_mean_exp`, which has the same value for all rows of the same country (so a line would be better).

-The group of 9 variables `ideolparty_A:ideolparty_I`, which do not have constant values across countries, but I'd like to take the mean of each of them for every country, so the value would be a constant. In this case, I'd like to draw points, circles, little shapes, not lines because it would be easier to visualize (lines would coincide and pollute the plot).  I could take the means with `dplyr::summarize` and match into the dataset again, but there might be an easier way to plot the group means directly .

So, here is the code I use for making the first part of the plot:

```
databind<- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = ideol_self:ideol_voted_LH_PL,
    names_to = "variable",
    values_to = "value"
  )
```

With pivot_longer I put these two variables in the same column, which allows me to plot them together in each density plot:

```
ggplot(data=databind, aes(x=value, group = variable)) +
  geom_density( alpha=.1)   +
  facet_wrap(~country, ncol=5) +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(size=5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size = 5),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size = 5),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 5),
        panel.spacing = unit(0.3, "lines"),
        legend.position="bottom" 
  ) + labs (x="Ideologia")
```

That produces something like this :

[image: Plot]

How could I add these other variables to get something like this (I've just drew by hand, for one country, a line and some points to make it easier to understand the outcome I want, this is not based in the data):

[image]

Maybe [this other SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330790/insert-mean-line-in-density-plot-for-multiple-facets-using-geom-vline) question has answers that might be useful, but I wasn't capable of writing the whole code for what I want here:

Below a code to produce a sample of my dataset:

```
structure(list(country = c("United States of America", "Slovenia", 
"Switzerland", "Argentina", "Canada", "Germany", "Spain", "Slovenia", 
"Czech Republic", "Spain", "United States of America", "New Zealand", 
"Czech Republic", "Czech Republic", "Switzerland", "Norway", 
"Albania", "Australia", "Hong Kong", "Israel", "Japan", "Mexico", 
"New Zealand", "Argentina", "Brazil", "Iceland", "Brazil", "Australia", 
"Poland", "Norway", "Mexico", "Latvia", "Thailand", "Greece", 
"Turkey", "Mexico", "Latvia", "Greece", "Serbia", "Ireland", 
"Canada", "Finland", "Denmark", "Mexico", "Ireland", "Germany", 
"Belgium", "Denmark", "Switzerland", "Canada", "Czech Republic", 
"Hong Kong", "Canada", "Netherlands", "Belgium", "Norway", "Iceland", 
"Republic of Korea", "Netherlands", "Norway", "Mexico", "United States of America", 
"Romania", "Japan", "Norway", "Norway", "Canada", "Poland", "Norway", 
"Greece", "Canada", "Great Britain", "Canada", "Australia", "Denmark", 
"Canada", "Russian Federation", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Israel", 
"United States of America", "Italy", "Iceland", "Austria", "Turkey", 
"Canada", "Philippines", "Latvia", "Ireland", "Canada", "France", 
"Switzerland", "Netherlands", "Ireland", "Israel", "Poland", 
"Israel", "Finland", "Norway", "Slovenia", "Israel", "Argentina", 
"Peru", "New Zealand", "Spain", "Serbia", "United States of America", 
"Albania", "Austria", "Netherlands", "Germany", "Romania", "Netherlands", 
"Philippines", "Greece", "Switzerland", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Switzerland", 
"Slovenia", "Netherlands", "Denmark", "Great Britain", "Belgium", 
"New Zealand", "Japan", "Norway", "Canada", "France", "Germany"
), ideol_self = c(6, NA, 7, 4, NA, 3, 5, NA, 7, 2, NA, 2, 7, 
8, 6, 4, 0, 5, 5, 2, 5, NA, NA, 5, NA, 7, 10, 7, 5, 4, 4, 5, 
5, 6, 9, 9, 5, NA, 9, 7, NA, 7, 4, 10, 5, NA, 7, 4, NA, NA, 8, 
NA, 7, 4, 3, 8, 4, NA, 3, 7, 0, NA, 4, NA, 3, 7, NA, NA, 0, 8, 
NA, 2, NA, 5, NA, 5, NA, 9, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4, 2, 2, NA, 9, 9, 10, 
7, 6, 7, 5, NA, 8, 5, 5, 6, 3, 5, 7, 4, 10, 8, NA, 5, 4, 0, 2, 
7, 6, 7, 9, 5, 6, 5, NA, NA, 4, 7, 5, 8, 5, NA, NA, 5, 7, 7, 
5, 4), ideol_voted_LH_PL = c(NA, 7, NA, 3, NA, 2, 3, NA, 8, 1, 
NA, 2, NA, 9, NA, 3, 0, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 
NA, NA, 5, NA, 8, 5, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 7, 4, NA, 
NA, 4, 8, 4, 7, NA, 10, NA, NA, 4, 3, NA, 4, NA, 3, 9, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 8, 1, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 10, 4, 
8, NA, 8, NA, 0, 2, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, 7, 4, NA, 9, 7, 6, 
8, 3, 5, NA, 4, 9, 7, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, 8, 9, NA, 6, NA, 5, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA), ideolparty_A = c(5, 
7, 9, 3, NA, 4, 8, 2, 8, 5, NA, 8, 1, 2, NA, 6, 9, 5, 10, 4, 
5, NA, NA, 8, NA, 3, 10, 9, 8, 5, 6, 5, 5, NA, 9, 10, 5, 5, 7, 
7, NA, 7, 7, 5, 8, 4, 8, 7, 10, NA, 10, NA, 3, 5, 3, 6, 8, NA, 
5, 2, 0, NA, 3, NA, 3, 8, NA, 4, 3, 5, NA, 2, NA, 8, NA, 7, NA, 
9, 5, 2, 9, 7, 7, 0, 10, NA, 5, 9, 10, 4, 8, 10, 10, NA, 0, 7, 
6, 8, 3, 5, 5, 4, 9, 7, 8, 8, 10, 10, 2, 9, 9, NA, 6, 10, 5, 
3, NA, NA, 10, 2, 5, 8, 4, NA, NA, 5, 4, 9, 7, 4), ideolparty_B = c(1, 
7, 4, NA, NA, 10, 5, 8, 4, 9, NA, 2, 8, 8, NA, 10, 10, 5, 0, 
5, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, 10, 2, 9, 8, 6, 8, 5, NA, 3, 0, 5, 4, 
6, 8, NA, 4, 4, 9, 6, 4, 8, 4, 3, NA, 3, NA, 7, 4, 2, 7, 4, NA, 
7, 9, 10, NA, 5, NA, 8, 10, NA, 0, 7, 8, NA, 10, NA, 1, NA, 8, 
10, 5, 10, 8, 3, 0, 4, 10, 2, NA, 5, 3, 10, 7, 3, 5, 6, NA, 3, 
5, 6, 10, 10, NA, 5, NA, 0, 2, 3, 2, 5, 0, 5, 5, 5, 7, 6, 5, 
10, 6, NA, NA, NA, 5, 8, 4, 5, NA, NA, 5, 7, 3, 5, 6), ideolparty_C = c(NA, 
7, 8, NA, NA, 10, 3, 5, 9, 1, NA, 1, 1, 9, NA, 8, 10, 5, 5, 8, 
5, NA, NA, 7, NA, 2, 0, 3, 3, 7, 3, 5, 5, NA, 6, NA, 6, 1, 4, 
4, NA, 8, 9, 5, 4, 4, 3, 8, 7, NA, 0, NA, 1, 4, 4, 10, 5, NA, 
6, 8, 10, NA, 5, NA, 7, 10, NA, 0, 9, 10, NA, 4, NA, 5, NA, 7, 
NA, 10, 0, 8, NA, 8, 5, 10, 5, NA, NA, 5, 0, 3, 7, 8, 4, NA, 
4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 5, 2, 7, 0, NA, 1, 0, NA, 8, 10, 4, NA, 7, 7, 
2, 0, 5, NA, NA, NA, 2, 8, 5, 5, NA, NA, 3, 6, 6, 6, 7), ideolparty_D = c(NA, 
7, 6, NA, NA, 4, NA, 6, 4, NA, NA, 3, 9, 1, NA, 3, 5, NA, 5, 
8, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 8, 2, 3, 0, 5, NA, 0, NA, 10, 
10, 6, 6, NA, 3, 2, 2, NA, 4, 10, 7, 5, NA, 3, NA, 0, 3, 7, 5, 
7, NA, 6, 1, 10, NA, 5, NA, 1, 2, NA, 8, 5, 7, NA, 5, NA, 8, 
NA, 4, 10, 6, 4, 7, NA, 0, 1, 5, 1, NA, 5, 9, 0, 5, 10, 7, 8, 
NA, 8, 4, 10, 4, 2, 5, 7, NA, 0, NA, 3, 9, NA, 0, 7, 8, 0, NA, 
4, 5, 5, 4, NA, NA, NA, 3, 6, 7, NA, NA, NA, 4, 2, 0, 10, 3), 
    ideolparty_E = c(NA, 1, 4, NA, NA, 7, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, 
    10, 6, NA, 7, 0, 5, 5, 1, 5, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 10, 10, 1, 
    5, 3, 0, 5, NA, 6, NA, 5, 0, 6, 6, NA, 5, 8, 2, 7, 4, 2, 
    2, 1, NA, 10, NA, NA, 6, NA, 5, 5, NA, 3, 6, 10, NA, 9, NA, 
    0, 9, NA, 10, 5, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 0, NA, 3, 
    NA, 8, 5, 0, 6, NA, 5, 1, 10, 3, 1, 4, 4, NA, 9, NA, 10, 
    3, 3, 5, 8, 5, 0, NA, 3, 6, NA, 0, 2, 3, 6, NA, 4, 5, 0, 
    8, NA, NA, 6, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, 4, 5, NA, 0, 4), ideolparty_F = c(NA, 
    NA, 5, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 5, 5, 
    NA, 5, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, 7, 2, 0, 5, 
    NA, 6, NA, 5, 6, 5, 7, NA, 5, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, NA, 5, 
    NA, NA, 5, 3, 4, 4, NA, 3, 6, 10, NA, NA, NA, 4, 7, NA, NA, 
    1, 9, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 10, 2, NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, 9, 
    3, NA, 9, 0, 5, NA, 2, 5, 5, NA, 9, NA, 10, 6, 5, 5, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, NA, 5, NA, 9, 1, 5, 7, NA, 6, 5, 5, 5, NA, NA, 
    0, 4, 2, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 5, 2), ideolparty_G = c(NA, 
    7, 7, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, 0, 4, NA, NA, 7, 5, NA, 
    NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, 0, 5, NA, 
    7, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 7, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 8, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 1, NA, NA, 6, 7, NA, NA, 3, NA, 4, 2, 
    NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 5, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    7, 5, 5, 5, 8, 0, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, NA, 5, 4, NA, 5, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 9, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, NA, 1, 10
    ), ideolparty_H = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 10, NA, 5, NA, 0, 5, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 5, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2, NA, NA, 6, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, 5, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, 8, NA, 4, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 0, NA, NA, 9, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    4, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 4), ideolparty_I = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, 7, NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), party_mean_exp = c(5, 
    5, 5.57142857142857, 4.88888888888889, 4.2, 5, 4.16666666666667, 
    5, 5.22222222222222, 4.33333333333333, 5, 5.22222222222222, 
    5.22222222222222, 5.85714285714286, 5.57142857142857, 4.75, 
    5, 4.5, 5.83333333333333, 5.4, 5, 4.6, 5.25, 4.88888888888889, 
    5, 4.33333333333333, 5.44444444444444, 4.5, 5.75, 4.75, 3.5, 
    5.57142857142857, 5, 5.14285714285714, 6.5, 3.75, 5.66666666666667, 
    4.33333333333333, 5.875, 5.16666666666667, 4.2, 5.71428571428571, 
    5, 3.5, 4.5, 4.875, 5, 4.875, 5.57142857142857, 4.2, 6, 4.625, 
    4.2, 6, NaN, 4.75, 5, 4.6, 5, 4.75, 3.5, 5.6, 5, 5, 4.75, 
    4.75, 4.2, 5.75, NaN, 5.14285714285714, 4.2, 4.75, 4.2, 4.2, 
    4.875, 5, 5, 5.11111111111111, 5, 5.4, 5.6, 4.5, 5.2, 5.85714285714286, 
    5.66666666666667, 4.2, 5.77777777777778, 5.5, 4.5, 4.2, 4.28571428571429, 
    5.57142857142857, 5, 4.16666666666667, 6.66666666666667, 
    5, 6.66666666666667, 5, 4.75, 5.85714285714286, 5, 4.88888888888889, 
    6, 5.22222222222222, NaN, 5.875, 5, 5, 5.85714285714286, 
    5, 5, 4.83333333333333, 5, NaN, 4.33333333333333, 5.875, 
    4.42857142857143, 4.11111111111111, 5.875, 6, 5, 4.875, 4.75, 
    NaN, 6, 4, 4.75, 4.2, 4.28571428571429, 5)), row.names = c(NA, 
-130L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: To keep it simple. You have a density plot which shows the distribution of your variable `value`? Then you try to plot a mean from whatever to the same plot? Or do you want to plot the distribuiton of the mean? If you want to plot the mean from your `ideolparty_A:ideolparty_I` I think this will interfere with the y axis of your density plot?

Comment: I want the mean by group (country means) of ideolparty_A, ideolparty_B, etc.